# Custom Fluid Content elements not detected

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using the latest beta5 of Typo3 6.2, with the development branch of fluidcontent, flux and vhs.

The Fluid Content Element is visible, but no type:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s254/sh/e6af43fa-be0f-498f-88f9-27655bf8afea/b63bb23242890430c906a136123f5a39

Typoscript file is included.

Here is my TS:

```
plugin.tx_kpcolcontent {
    view {
        label = Column Content
        extensionKey = kpcolcontent
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_kpcolpages.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_kpcolpages.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_kpcolpages.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

The template is in EXT:kpcolcontent/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Columns.html

```
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}

<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="Configuration">
  <flux:flexform id="columns" label="Columns">
    <flux:flexform.grid>
        <flux:flexform.grid.row>
            <flux:flexform.grid.column>
                <flux:flexform.content name="left" label="Left content" />
            </flux:flexform.grid.column>
            <flux:flexform.grid.column>
                <flux:flexform.content name="right" label="Right content" />
            </flux:flexform.grid.column>
        </flux:flexform.grid.row>
    </flux:flexform.grid>
  </flux:flexform>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Preview">
  <flux:widget.grid />
</f:section>

<f:section name="Main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <flux:flexform.renderContent area="left" />
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <flux:flexform.renderContent area="right" />
    </div>
  </div>
</f:section>
```

Comment: It maybe has something to do with the CMS being beta and the extension-branch being under development :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPO3 6.2x with flux

Download from:
Flux: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux
Fluidpages: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidpages (For page template)
fluidcontent: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent
vhs: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs

Typoscript:

```
plugin.tx_fluidpages.collections.kpcolcontent {
   templateRootPath = {$filepaths.private}Templates/
    partialRootPath = {$filepaths.private}Partials/
    layoutRootPath = {$filepaths.private}Layouts/
}
plugin.tx_fed.fce.kpcolcontent{
    templateRootPath = {$filepaths.private}Elements/Content/
    partialRootPath = {$filepaths.private}Partials/
    layoutRootPath = {$filepaths.private}Layouts/
}
```

Template file EXT:kpcolcontent/Resources/Private/Templates/**Elements**/Content/Columns.html

```
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
{namespace flux=Tx_Flux_ViewHelpers}

<f:layout name="Content" />

<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:flexform wizardTab="Custom Elements" label="Two Column Container" id="twocolumn" description="" icon="">
        <flux:flexform.grid>
            <flux:flexform.grid.row>
                <flux:flexform.grid.column>
                    <flux:flexform.content name="left" label="Left content" />
                </flux:flexform.grid.column>
                <flux:flexform.grid.column>
                    <flux:flexform.content name="right" label="Right content" />
                </flux:flexform.grid.column>
            </flux:flexform.grid.row>
        </flux:flexform.grid>
    </flux:flexform>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Preview">
  <flux:widget.grid />
</f:section>

<f:section name="Main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <flux:flexform.renderContent area="left" />
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <flux:flexform.renderContent area="right" />
    </div>
  </div>
</f:section>
```

Content layout: EXT:kpcolcontent/Resources/Private/Layouts/Content.html

```
<f:layout name="Content" />
<f:render section="Main" />
```

Enjoy TYPO3 6.2x + Flux + Fluidcontent

Comment: Works if I add the typoscript in the backend Setup field, doesn't seam to work in the extension TS. The select also doesn't have the label, the generated .FED_CONTENT has a empty title key. When switching to it also throws an error about a view helper not being loaded. I'll wait some more until things stabilize and do what I need some other way.